# Format conditional statements according to precedence in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, code-formatting

Is there any way to make IntelliJ IDEA format conditional statements as Eclipse does (according to condition precedence)?

**Eclipse**

```
public boolean apply(NewsDocument document) {
  return "EDG".equalsIgnoreCase(document.getFeedShortName())
      && (isNullOrEmpty(document.getEdgarFormType())
          || "10-K".equalsIgnoreCase(document.getEdgarFormType())
          || "20-F".equalsIgnoreCase(document.getEdgarFormType()))
      && documentWithinRecentFiscalYear(document);
}

return accessLevel == inFeature.getAccessLevel()
    || accessLevel != AccessLevel.NO_ACCESS
        && inFeature.getAccessLevel() == AccessLevel.NOT_SET;

return hasConnectionHolder() && getConnectionHolder().isRollbackOnly()
    || getHibernateSessionHolder() != null
        && getHibernateSessionHolder().isRollbackOnly()
    || getTxContextHolder() != null
        && getTxContextHolder().isRollbackOnly();
```

**IntelliJ IDEA** *(Settings|Code Style|Java|Wrapping and Braces|Binary expressions|Align parenthesised when multiline = **false**)*

```
public boolean apply(NewsDocument document) {
  return "EDG".equalsIgnoreCase(document.getFeedShortName())
      && (isNullOrEmpty(document.getEdgarFormType())
      || "10-K".equalsIgnoreCase(document.getEdgarFormType())
      || "20-F".equalsIgnoreCase(document.getEdgarFormType()))
      && documentWithinRecentFiscalYear(document);
}

return accessLevel == inFeature.getAccessLevel()
    || accessLevel != AccessLevel.NO_ACCESS
    && inFeature.getAccessLevel() == AccessLevel.NOT_SET;

return hasConnectionHolder() && getConnectionHolder().isRollbackOnly()
    || getHibernateSessionHolder() != null
    && getHibernateSessionHolder().isRollbackOnly()
    || getTxContextHolder() != null
    && getTxContextHolder().isRollbackOnly();
```

**IntelliJ IDEA** *(Settings|Code Style|Java|Wrapping and Braces|Binary expressions|Align parenthesised when multiline = **true**)*

```
public boolean apply(NewsDocument document) {
  return "EDG".equalsIgnoreCase(document.getFeedShortName())
      && (isNullOrEmpty(document.getEdgarFormType())
              || "10-K".equalsIgnoreCase(document.getEdgarFormType())
              || "20-F".equalsIgnoreCase(document.getEdgarFormType()))
      && documentWithinRecentFiscalYear(document);
}

return accessLevel == inFeature.getAccessLevel()
    || accessLevel != AccessLevel.NO_ACCESS
    && inFeature.getAccessLevel() == AccessLevel.NOT_SET;

return hasConnectionHolder() && getConnectionHolder().isRollbackOnly()
    || getHibernateSessionHolder() != null
    && getHibernateSessionHolder().isRollbackOnly()
    || getTxContextHolder() != null
    && getTxContextHolder().isRollbackOnly();
```

IntelliJ IDEA version: 2017.3.5

Answer (score 0):

you just import you Code Formatter Settings from Eclipse

- All you need is to export settings from Eclipse (go to Eclipse’s Preferences → Java → Code Style → Formatter and export the settings to an XML file via the Export All button.),
- open IntelliJ IDEA Settings → Code Style → Java, click Manage, and import that XML file by simply clicking Import.

Comment: Yes, I tried this but it simply doesn't work. Looks like Idea doesn't support this kind of formatting. What really works is using this plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter. But as for me it is a short term solution.